# Changing GORM table name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm fighting to get the following mapping working in Grails 1.3.1 and MySQL:

```
class Login {

    int id
    String email

    static mappings = {
        table 'my_table'
        id column: "Mgr_id"
        version false
    }
}
```

No matter what I do the queries that are being issued refer to "schema.login" table instead of "schema.my_table". This is very frustrating... Can anyone answer why this might not be working?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please forgive my blindness... The static is called `mapping` not `mappings`... eh. Shame on me...

Block should be

```
static mapping = {
    table 'my_table'
    id column: "Mgr_id"
    version false
}
```

Comment: Note that the syntax for disabling optimistic locking is "version false" - no colon.

Comment: answered in 11 minutes, nice!