# GORM choose which tables will open and which ones will not

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a project that uses GORM, I want to choose which tables to create as I run the project.

Anyone know how to do it? Can I create a new profile for this?

Comment: Hmm, It's not clear what do you want to ask? If u need to override table name for Domain object just see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066086/changing-gorm-table-name

Comment: I don't want to change names.
I have a lot of tables in the project, which I don't always want to be created in DB that software comes up for the first time

Comment: In this case, you need to change 'dbCreate' property to 'validate'
 https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0/guide/conf.html#dataSource. Is it?

Comment: why would someone want to do that?

Comment: It's an interesting question, maybe the author will answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to have all of the tables created when the application starts up, or none of them. It is not possible to have *some* of them created. The [configuration parameter which controls this behaviour](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0/guide/conf.html#dataSource) is the datasource's `dbCreate`